User-scoped setting change lost after restart
I've defined a suser-scoped setting named SizeSliderValue.
In the top of the cs code;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Threading;
    
namespace WPFTesting
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
    
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.SizeSliderValue > sizeSlider.Minimum)
            {
                sizeSlider.Value = Properties.Settings.Default.SizeSliderValue;
            }
            else
            {
                sizeSlider.Value = 16;
            }

Then in value changed event:
private void sizeSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.SizeSliderValue = (int)sizeSlider.Value;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

I set a breakpoint and it's doing fine the two lines in the ValueChanged event.
But then when I run the application over again the value of SizeSliderValue is 16.
I set a breakpoint in the constructor as well and it's reaching the line
sizeSlider.Value = Properties.Settings.Default.SizeSliderValue;

but the value is 16.
Maybe the problem is that I set the default value of the slider to 16 in the xaml code ?
<Slider x:Name="sizeSlider" Minimum="10" Maximum="30" Value="16" TickFrequency="1" 
    IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="400"
    ValueChanged="sizeSlider_ValueChanged"/>

Here is a screenshot of the settings file:


Has the assembly version changed? User-scoped settings are stored in an application and version-specific folder. If the version changes due to eg auto-numbering, the old settings are no longer visible. You can call Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade() to bring them forward. Check the accepted answer to this question

In the possibly duplicate question, the answer is to call Upgrade() only if the version changes. To detect this (there's no default mechanism) a user-scoped UpgradeRequired setting is uses whose default is True. After upgrading, that's set to False before saving

Solve it by adding  a flag and a tracker to track is there are changes.
at the top i added:
private int trackSliderSize = 0;
private bool isInitializing = true;  // To track if the app is initializing

constructor
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // During initialization, suppress the ValueChanged event
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.SizeSliderValue > sizeSlider.Minimum)
    {
        sizeSlider.Value = Properties.Settings.Default.SizeSliderValue;
        trackSliderSize = (int)sizeSlider.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        sizeSlider.Value = 16;
    }

    // Set isInitializing to false once the initialization is complete
    isInitializing = false;

    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
    LoadDrives();  // Load drives on startup
}

and value changed event
private void sizeSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    // If the app is still initializing, we don't want to handle this event
    if (isInitializing)
        return;

    // If the user has changed the value
    if ((int)sizeSlider.Value != trackSliderSize)
    {
        // Save the new value in settings
        Properties.Settings.Default.SizeSliderValue = (int)sizeSlider.Value;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

        // Update the tracked size
        trackSliderSize = (int)sizeSlider.Value;
    }
}

now it's working perfect.
the problem was that because i update the value in the constructor it was triggering the valuechanged event code and keep saving the current value and not the new value. now it's saving to settings only if there is a new value.
